# How can you store a file handle in python similar to perl?

Tags: python, perl

How can I perform this code in python

```
open( OUTPUT, $outputfile )
and $struct{'existing'} = *OUTPUT{IO}
$struct{'output'} = *STDOUT{IO};
```

Comment: As perl code, that's a terrible abuse of a global filehandle. You should instead use a lexical:

Comment: `my $outputfh;
 open( $outputfh, $outputfile ) and $struct{existing} = $outputfh;`

Comment: @LeoNerd It's not my script. I am just tasked with converting it to python, and got tripped up on the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "file handle" in Python is a reference to a [`file` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), which is handled like any other name in Python. Opening a file returns a file object:

```
output = open(outputfile)
```

This reference can be stored in a data structure:

```
struct["existing"] = output
```

Comment: And if you're looking for `stdout` you can use `sys.stdout`.